# Python and MySQL compile version

Tags: python, mysql

How do I check if my python and mysql are 32 bit installations or 64 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `file` command :

> file `which python`
>
> file `which mysql`

The `file` command is available on all UNIX-based systems.

Answer (score 2):

```
readelf -h $(which mysqld) | grep Class
readelf -h $(which python) | grep Class
```

Seems to work for me. The readelf command is part of the GNU binutils.